# Amazon Linux vs Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have developed a web service(using ruby/sinatra/sqs) which runs on Linux Red Hat. I am planning to move this on a EC2 instance. I see that Amazon provides a linux version of its own. Is there any reason why I should use Amazon Linux on EC2 instead of Red Hat?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ 
Please check before commenting. And I am not sure why this is not the correct place to post this question?

Comment: I learned something new :) It's not the correct place because there are n't many sysadmins here. The guys over at Serverfault should be able to give you better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Amazon's Linux AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) is most closely related to Centos, a Red Hat variant.  The biggest benefit I've found from using it is their use of the [pvgrub](http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/PvGrub) boot loader.  It makes it trivial to compile and reboot into new or custom kernels.

Besides that, there are many nice-to-haves, such as patches being automatically applied on boot, having many AWS-related command line tools installed by default, and pre-configuration for in-cloud yum repositories.

Comment: Mor information, about corresponding Red Hat versions in particular, is available here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=194752